# This is regarding copying and transferring in Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy, transfer

Having trouble with transferring files with (cp) usage on Powershell. I am not able to transfer from (ex: Desktop to Temp files). Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your actual code? Hardly.

Comment: ah...guess maybe that would help...well can you possibly show me from just a simple code line of cp transferring a file?

Comment: If you type `help <some command> -examples` you will get examples. So `help cp -examples`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
cp $userprofile\desktop\your_file $temp
```

Replace your_file with the name (including wildcards if necessary) of your file(s).

Comment: thank you for the right path but it didn't quite work for me so I tweeked it a bit and it worked out!

> cp newfile -destination C:\Users\Me\Desktop